# R library gets deleted when Rstudio restarts (ubuntu)

Tags: r, azure, ubuntu

I use the Rstudio pre-installed on Azure, ubuntu.

Every time when the server crashes or R connection lost, everything in `.libPaths()[1]` gets deleted; However, other users on this VM don't experience this problem.

**How to fix it?**

My guessing is that whenever the connection restarts R runs some kind of scripts which re-create the folder (i.e. `.libPaths()[1]`).

- `.libPaths()[1]` originally refers to another folder, but I've changed `"etc/R/Renviron" (R_LIBS_USER=${R_LIBS_USER-'~/R/library'})` so now it points to `"/home/profile_name/R/library"`.

Comment: You could try [this](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/214993747-Rstudio-crashes-freezes-when-I-try-to-open-an-R-project).

Comment: When you start R, does `.libPaths()` show your added path to HOME subfolder?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik yes it shows. `.libPaths()[1]` essentially.

Comment: I think this is server issue, not R. Are you running ubuntu in some sort of a container?